# Replace text with links

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, hyperlink

I need to loop through an array and compare items with a string and if it contains the item from the array, to update that text in the string to be a link

Is there a way to do it without constructing DOM markup strings in the viewModel?

This is what I was able to do so far based on Jeroen's answer. If you click run code snippet you can see what it's currently doing versus what I need it to do

```js
$(function() {
  var tvm = new testViewModel();
  tvm.addLink();
  ko.applyBindings(tvm);
})
var Link = function(txt, hrf) {
  this.txt = ko.observable(txt);
  this.hrf = ko.observable(hrf);
}
var testViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.links = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.addLink = function() {
    console.log('here');
    self.links.push(new Link('Sam', 'Open?name=Sam'));
    self.links.push(new Link('Test', 'Open?name=Test'));
    self.links.push(new Link('Maria', 'Open?name=Maria'));
    var wholeStr = 'Maria is testing the new system';
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
This is what it's doing: <div data-bind="foreach: links">
  <a data-bind="attr: { href: hrf }, text: txt"></a>
</div>
This is what I want:
<a href="Open?name=Maria">Maria</a> is <a href="Open?name=Test">test</a>ing the new system.
```

Now, it's just writing out the links from the array and not the whole string with parts of it being links. Where can I specify that the text that matches the text in the array should be replaced with links?

Thank you

Comment: Define *better*. The better way is that fits with your requirements.

Comment: You can make it with a lot of lines of code more (`document.createElement()`), so my guess your actual code is better than your wishes. However, I suggest to improve your code adding quotes to the tag and closing properly the `</a>`(you have `<\a>` and it's wrong): `<a href="doctoopen">' + textToLink + '</a>'`

Comment: thanks, good to know that is the way to go about it. It's still writing it out as text though even though I changed the quotes and the /

Comment: Do you have to append the text to an innerHTML or will knockout do that with this function? Else that's the issue.

Comment: Thank you! I had to specify html instead of text in the data-bind of the span tag. <span data-bind="html: $root.createLinks(name())"></span>